# dcast with value being text

Tags: r, tidyr

I'm looking to spread or dcast a data.frame where the value is a text string.

```
df = data.frame(employeeid = c(1,1,2,2),
                question=c('do you like milk?', 'do you like apples?', 'do you like milk?', 'do you like apples?'),
                Answer=c('Yes','No','No','No'))
```

I'm looking to pivot this to a wide format where column headers are the employee id and the questions. I've tried `df = spread(df,question,Answer)` but that doesn't seem to do it

Comment: Doesn't seem to do it how? You want column names to be both ID and question? Or is there a word missing?

Comment: @camille, it came out in the comments to my answer: there are dupes, so `dcast` uses warns about no explicit `fun_aggregate` and uses `length`, resulting in a numeric output, not the desired strings. (I agree that the question should have included that tidbit.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you had `dcast` in your title, I'll assume `data.table`:

```r
data.table::dcast(question ~ employeeid, data = df, value.var = "Answer")
#              question   1  2
# 1 do you like apples?  No No
# 2   do you like milk? Yes No
```

but an alternative:

```r
tidyr::spread(df, employeeid, Answer)
#              question   1  2
# 1 do you like apples?  No No
# 2   do you like milk? Yes No
```

**Edit**: since it appears you have dupes in the data, you can find the "most-occurring" answer with:

```r
most <- function(x) names(sort(table(x)))[1]
data.table::dcast(question~employeeid, data=df, value.var="Answer", fun.aggregate = most)
#              question   1   2
# 1 do you like apples? Yes Yes
# 2   do you like milk?  No Yes
```

Comment: so i used the dcast function but i get a message saying the aggregate function is missing and it defaults to length, which is incorrect.

Comment: I don't know what to say ... your data and this function works for me. This is demoed with `data.table-1.12.0` and `tidyr-0.8.2` on R-3.5.3.

Comment: Okay, that error is likely because you have duplicate id/question pairs. When that happens, even if you declare `value.var="Answer"`, it's going to give you the length of the pivoted groups. If this is a known condition, define a function that always returns the first or most-frequent element, but realize that you'll "lose data".

Comment: Another option would be to de-duplicate the data first: `df[ !duplicated(cbind(df$employeeid, df$question)),]`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I added aggregate.fun=min and that works.

Comment: Note that `min` on `character` does not always return exactly what you want. `min('2','11')` returns `'11'`.

Comment: Ted, if this solves your issue, please accept it. Thanks!